# How to measure memory usage of a Rack or Sinatra app?

Tags: ruby, memory-management, sinatra, rack

How do you measure memory usage of a Rack or Sinatra app?

I understand that probably depends a lot on how it is deployed.
But how do you get a basic idea of how much memory it uses?

Comment: can `top` or `htop` with process id would work

Answer (score 2):

If you're using passenger, you could try passenger-memory-stats which gives you a nice overview split up by site, otherwise you can get some idea of memory usage by using top, shift-M and looking for the ruby processes.

Answer (score 1):

Despite it's name, I've successfully used the [derailed_benchmarks gem](https://github.com/schneems/derailed_benchmarks) to dynamically benchmark memory usage in a Padrino (built on Sinatra) app. The [docs](https://github.com/schneems/derailed_benchmarks#rack-setup) describe how to do this for a non-Rails Rack app - you just need to define `DERAILED_APP` in a [simple Rake task](https://github.com/schneems/derailed_benchmarks#perfrake) to tell it how to boot your app.

It can be run with a real server (I use Unicorn) on your localhost and potentially even with your production database (define `DATABASE_URL`). It can also be used to test any endpoint and bypass authentication, if necessary. Use cases include memory use over time (to find leaks) and profiling gems/required library memory at boot for a given endpoint (lots of memory use at boot).

As an example, the command `bundle exec derailed exec perf:mem` gives the output below for my app's root at boot (here hiding < 3 MiB usage). Around 70 MiB tallies with what Heroku's stats are telling me on my production server. My app is called 'padfoot' btw.

`TOP: 71.75 MiB
  mechanize: 19.0898 MiB (Also required by: /Users/me/dev/padfoot/lib/parsers/transaction_table_parser.rb, /Users/me/dev/padfoot/lib/scrapers/app_details_scraper.rb, and 4 others)
    mechanize/pluggable_parsers: 11.1055 MiB
      mime/types: 10.9766 MiB (Also required by: /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request, /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/payload)
  padrino: 13.1016 MiB
    padrino-core: 8.0273 MiB (Also required by: padrino-cache, padrino-admin)
      padrino-core/application: 3.3555 MiB
      sinatra/base: 3.1406 MiB (Also required by: padrino-core/ext/sinatra, sinatra/main)
    padrino-helpers: 3.707 MiB (Also required by: padrino-cache, padrino-admin)
      padrino/rendering: 3.3203 MiB (Also required by: /Users/me/dev/padfoot/app/app.rb)
  /Users/me/dev/padfoot/config/apps.rb: 6.9805 MiB
    /Users/me/dev/padfoot/app/app.rb: 6.8906 MiB
  aws-sdk-core/s3: 6.3711 MiB
  /Users/me/dev/padfoot/lib/scrapers/gps/gps_scraper.rb: 4.25 MiB
    linguistics/en: 4.1523 MiB
  /Users/me/dev/padfoot/lib/scrapers/digimap/digimap_scraper.rb: 3.0547 MiB`